# Must be called from a blob upload callback request

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, gwt

I have implemented this GWT example for blobstore API in Java:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/

it works fine when POST is made via the client side form (inside a browser).

However, now I am sending files (images) to the same /upload service handler but from a python request inside my offline program (not browser):

```
r = requests.post(url+'upload', files= {'myFile': open('fig.jpeg', 'rb')})
```

and I get the following exception

> Must be called from a blob upload callback request

in the first line of (server side):

```
Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobs.get("myFile");
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 2):

That `/upload` handler is not meant for you to call directly, neither from the browser nor a python application. Instead, your application will need to make two calls: the first to your server to get a temporary URL, then the second to upload to that URL, which will connect with the blobstore directly. Your server should generate that temporary URL using `blobstoreService.createUploadUrl`, as described in step 1 of [this section](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob) of the documentation you linked.

During the course of the second call (the upload), the blobstore will directly call your upload handler to inform your app about the new blob(s). That is what `blobstoreService.getUploads(req)` knows how to interpret.

So your python application will make 2 calls, and your server will also handle 2 requests. The first request comes directly from the python application simply requesting the url. The second request will happen *during* the upload, but will actually come directly from the blobstore.

Comment: Dear Eric! This makes sense:) Thank you for the quick reply. I will go into details!

Comment: Is there a better way to upload files (images) to blobstore from my python application?

Comment: No, this is the best way. It is the way Google themselves outline in the documentation we linked. You could look into using Google Cloud Storage instead, which you can upload to this same way (see [this section](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage) in the docs), but also provides other options. I am not as familiar with those other options though, so I'm afraid that's the most help I can be there.

Answer (score 0):

### Find below sample code to understand callback with flask and python

#### project> app.py

```
import datetime
import time
import requests # to make get and post requests
import json
from flask import Flask, Response, request, render_template  #  request : is not same as requests its flask request on url

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] = True

# 3. no need to give any url mapping for callback function,
# this will get call once demo() return back to hello() at post request call.
def callbacks(response, *args, **kwargs):
    print(" -- callbacks starts -- : ", datetime.datetime.now().time())

    if response.status_code == 200:
        #print(response.text)
        print(" -- callback end -- : ", datetime.datetime.now().time());
        #return response
        # return Response(response, status=200)   do not return response here this will cause problem when


# 2. on post request call made from hello(): resp = requests.post(......)
@app.route('/demo' , methods=['POST']) # validate request of type methods=['POST']
def demo():
    print("Post request received : ", datetime.datetime.now().time())

    if request.method == 'POST':  # check request of type post
        time.sleep(5)   # some sleep time to check if callback is working
        print("Post response sent to callback : ", datetime.datetime.now().time())
        # return response with data received from request.data  and status = 200
        return Response(request.data, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, status=200)



# 1. run this file and hit url localhost:5000/  to execute ( GET request)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    print("Hello start : ", datetime.datetime.now().time())
    url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';         # url will return json list

    data = requests.get(
                            url=url,
                            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                        )   # get request to get json data from url using requests lib

    # check if flask request is get
    if request.method == 'GET':

        # post request to another url /demo with data as a json as argument ,
        # imp : hooks to link callback function once /demo url returns response callback will start execute
        resp = requests.post( url = 'http://localhost:5000/demo',
                              headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                              json = data.json(),
                              hooks={'response': callbacks }
                            )

    print("Hello End : ",datetime.datetime.now().time())
    # render with html template with argument as data and result
    return render_template('index.html', result=resp.json(), data=data.json())
    #                OR
    # return Response(response='OK', status=resp.status_code) # return response with 200 or 'OK'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

### create file index.html and copy below code

#### project/templates> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>JSON OUTPUT</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr><td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Email</td></tr>
            {% for d in data %}
                <tr><td>{{ d['id'] }}</td><td>{{ d['name'] }}</td><td>{{ d['email'] }}</td></tr>
            {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <div>{{ result }}</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

#### run with cmd >  python app.py